# Telerik HTML5 ReportViewer sending empty parameterValues in Internet Explorer

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, telerik, internet-explorer-11, telerik-reporting

I have a simple report viewer page set up like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Telerik HTML5 Report Viewer</title>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

<link href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.930/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.930/styles/kendo.blueopal.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!--kendo.all.min.js can be used as well instead of the following custom Kendo UI subset-->
<script src="/ReportViewer/js/telerikReportViewer.kendo-11.1.17.614.min.js"></script>

<script src="/ReportViewer/js/telerikReportViewer-11.1.17.614.min.js"></script>

<style>
    #reportViewer1 {
        position: absolute;
        left: 5px;
        right: 5px;
        top: 5px;
        bottom: 5px;
        overflow: hidden;
        font-family: Verdana, Arial;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="reportViewer1">
    loading...
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#reportViewer1")
            .telerik_ReportViewer({
                serviceUrl: "/api/reports",
                reportSource: {
                    report: "FrontEnd.Reports.WeeklySnapshot, FrontEnd",
                    parameters: {
                        ID: 1,
                        From: "2017-06-05",
                        To: "2017-06-11",
                    }
                },
            });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

As far as I can tell, this should all be set up correctly.  When I run this locally in Firefox 54, everything loads properly.  I see this POST in Firebug:

```
{
   "report":"FrontEnd.Reports.WeeklySnapshot, FrontEnd",
   "parameterValues":
   {
        "ID":"1",
        "From":"2017-06-05T00:00:00.000Z",
        "To":"2017-06-11T00:00:00.000Z"
   }
}
```

But, when I run it locally in Internet Explorer, I see this POST in F12:

```
{
   "report":"FrontEnd.Reports.WeeklySnapshot, FrontEnd",
   "parameterValues":{}
}
```

So nothing loads.  Why is `parameterValues` empty?  I haven't been able to find anything via Google.

Thanks

PS. This is using the latest version of Telerik Reporting: R2 2017 SP1 (11.1.17.614) in a .NET 4.6.1 application

Comment: I don't have an answer but my reports are working with parameters in IE11(and chrome) using Reporting 11.0.17.222 with the Kendo 2017.2.504 kendo.all.min.js(rather than the subset provided by Reporting) and the jquery.min.js packaged with Kendo, which is jQuery v1.12.3, instead of the jQuery CDN.  The only other difference I have is that I call .telerik_ReportViewer() from a JS source file after fetching the viewer page as I reuse the same page/viewer for all my reports with the reportSource set dynamically at runtime, instead of hardcoded in document.ready(), but that should be irrelevant.

Comment: Well, it seems to be working now.  Not really sure why